# Wireless Hardware Not Found On HP ProBook 4510s

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp

Is there a way I can install the Wireless propriety drivers offline? As I cannot connect to the internet and there is no LAN connection availability. Maybe I can get the files separately and install them through Terminal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is one option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Otherwise you can download the packages manually [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), copy them to your computer via a flash drive or writable cd, and install them with the instructions [here](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg21t2.htm). Remember to pick up the dependencies as well if you do it this way.